# Avoid changing line in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have my `HTML` structure as follows:

```
<div id="id1">
   <h1>my name </h1><h3><a href="mailto:myemail_id">myemailid@xyz.com</a></h3>
</div>
```

The code automatically brings the `<h3>` on the next line. However, I want it next to `<h1>` without any line-change.

CSS:

```
#id1{
    width: 900px;
    padding: 30px; 
    background: #FFF;
    text-align:center;
}

#id1 h3{
    font-family:Arial;
    white-space:nowrap
}
```

How can I modify to achieve my desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use more semantic markup or simply modify the elements with CSS:

```
#id1 h1, #id1 h3 { display: inline; }
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML headings behaviours with `display: block` by default. So they won't share same line with any other `relative` element.

Set their display to `inline-block`, and they will render one after the other, just as you expect.